# How to create html table with 100 unique td using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to draw game board with 100 places using javascript.

I thought a table would be perfect for that - so every line will be tr, and every square is td. I manage to do this by this code above.

The problem that although I get my desired board visually – i actually just duplicate my tr 10 times.

I'm trying to give each square a unique id. 
I need some guidance here.

```
function createBoard() {
    var table = document.getElementById("puzzleBoard");
    table.innerHTML = "";
    for (var r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
        var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        table.appendChild(newRow);
        for (var c = -1; c < 9; c++) {
            var newCell = document.createElement("td");
            var cellName = (c + 1);
            newRow.appendChild(newCell);
            var newPiece = document.createElement("div");
            //newPiece.setAttribute("id", "cell-0"+cellName;);
            newPiece.innerHTML = "cell-0" + cellName;
            newCell.appendChild(newPiece);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in this do you specify any id of any kind?

Comment: Why not doing it like `id="cell-'+c+r+'"'`? and c from 0 to 9 and r from 0-9

Comment: after reading @MamaLord comment i figure what i missed. thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `cellName = (c + 1) * (r + 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
newPiece.innerHTML = `cell-${cellName}-row-${r}`;
```

Comment: Missing explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest unique identifier:

```
cellName++
```

Here the code:

```
function createBoard() {
    var table = document.getElementById("puzzleBoard");
    table.innerHTML = "";

    var cellName = 0;//<-- initialization

    for (var r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
        var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        table.appendChild(newRow);
        for (var c = -1; c < 9; c++) {
            var newCell = document.createElement("td");

            newRow.appendChild(newCell);
            var newPiece = document.createElement("div");
            newPiece.setAttribute("id", "cell-"+cellName);//<-- set id
            newPiece.innerHTML = "cell-"+cellName;

            cellName++;//<-- plus 1

            newCell.appendChild(newPiece);
        }
    }
}
```

Now we have a 10x10 matrix in which we can perform easier math operations (you are doing a game). Each cell have a number from 0 to 99.